# Are there any long-term health benefits/ disadvantages of wearing socks, especially woolies?

Tags: neurology, autoimmune-disease, cardiovascular-disease, blood-circulation, lasting-effects-duration

Are there any long-term health benefits/ disadvantages of wearing socks, especially woolies ?